# ngrok to expose local Angular app running on https and 4200 port

Tags: angular, https, ngrok

Which command to use to expose my local Angular app running on HTTPS:

```
https://localhost:4200
```

Usually I use `ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 4200` with Angular apps when it's just `http`.

Comment: When you run `ngrok http  ....`, there will be 2 links, 1 for http, 1 for https. You don't see it there ?

Comment: yes I see it .. but both points to my local `http://localhost;4200` not `httpS:\\localhost:4200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command to expose a local `https` server is :

```
ngrok http -host-header="localhost:4200" https://localhost:4200
```

Comment: facing this: ERR_NGROK_3004
ngrok gateway error

The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response.